# Create customized check boxes?

Tags: wpf, checkbox, styles, customization

Can anyone provide the XAML for creating customized check boxes. I have attached the image below. These check boxes have a square instead of a tick inside them. All efforts are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: google. "custom-looking" is a well-covered topic for WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to alter the `ControlTemplate` for the `CheckBox`. This article discusses one approach - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163497.aspx#S2

Comment: You can also find the default control template [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319.aspx)